# Indicate if a commenter downvoted the post they're commenting on

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

> "I didn't downvote, but... "

I'm kind of getting tired of that phrase...

If you don't want to expose the down-voter, that's fine. But at least expose him when he comments the post he down-voted. That way, the other people who comment wouldn't have to explicitly state that they didn't down-vote, because the mere fact that their comment "passed" (wasn't exposed), would denote that they're not the down-voters.

**Update:**
May I propose the abbreviation IDDB for this purpose...

Comment: Haha, very funny...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is probably not going to be a popular suggestion.

Comment: Downvote on Meta means people don't agree with you.  Though it's irresponsible for them to try and close a normal feature-request (and no I don't agree with it, but won't bother with the downvote on this one).

Comment: I did downvote this.  Honestly.

Answer (score 15):

Voting is supposed to be anonymous so people feel free to express their own opinions without fear of retaliation. Your proposal would undermine this principle, because we encourage downvoters to express why they downvoted so corrections and improvements can be made.

Remember, it's the commentor's choice to put that phrase in front of their comment. And in any case, people can lie **gasp**!

<sub>Yes, I did downvote this proposal. I don't care about being anonymous. :D</sub>

Comment: Have you thought of that at the same time you're discouraging everybody else from commenting because they don't want to be seen as potential down-voters? Of course, if they're particularly eager to comment, they might do so and put the seemingly obligatory "I didn't downvote but..." in there.

Comment: If you didn't feel strongly about it enough to downvote, then is it really important enough to comment on?

Answer (score 7):

> That way, the other people who comment wouldn't have to explicitly state that they didn't down-vote

They don't *have* to. And when they do, it just reinforces the whole "folks who comment voted" idea.

I'm tired of that phrase too, and the "+1/-1" prefixes, and "why the downvotes?" comments. But the solution isn't to tie voting and commenting together *more tightly*... It's to focus on leaving clear, constructive comments that address the content of the post and nothing more.

Comment: +1, but I wasn't the upvoter

Comment: I didn't upvote this, but I agree with it completely. I don't like downvoting a post and seeing other people feel like they have to issue a disclaimer when they comment, but the solution is not to paint downvoters' hands red.